# How to prevent Vercel routing to not finding the page

Tags: json, next.js, vercel, toml

I am building a project using NextJs and Vercel, but, when the users try to access a new page or route, the Vercel gives them the 404 error.

In other projects, I used Netlify as router and this error was fixed using the `netlify.toml` config file, but, I am not able to do the same using the `vercel.json` file.

Can you guys help me to turn this file:

`netlify.toml`

```
[[redirects]]
from = "/*"
to = "/index.html"
status = 200
```

Into a `vercel.json` config file?

I was trying with this settings:
`vercel.json`

```
{
    "rewrites": [{ "source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/index.html"}]
}
```

But it did not solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround is to use a [catch all route](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-routes) that immediately redirects to the index page. For example:

```
// [...404].jsx

export default function Page() {
  return null;
}

export function getServerSideProps() {
  return {
    redirect: {
      destination: '/',
      permanent: false,
    },
  };
}
```